# ESX Server VmWare - Disable virtual port attached to virtual switch

Tags: esx

**Background:**
When working on a physical network we come across a typical environment where storage boxes (NSM) are connected to switch port. We can enable or disable switch ports using putty.

**Objective:**
Similar fashion on ESX Server virtual machines (VM) are connected to virtual switch.Virtual switches contains Port Group to which more than 1 VM are attached.

**Query:**
1. Can we assign port number to VM on virtual switch ?
2. Is it possible to disable VM attached to virtual switch using port number ?

Software requirement:ESX Server / Hyper V, vSphere Client.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is certainly possible.

1. If you right-click your VM and choose 'Edit Settings', click on the network adapter you'd like to modify and then click 'Switch to advanced settings' (blue text under 'Network Connection' section on the right), you can choose a switch and a Port ID.  The port ID corresponds to the virtual switchport that you want your VM to connect to.
2. Using your vSphere client, go to Home->Inventory->Networking.  Click on the name of your dvPortGroup (distributed port group).  Next, click the 'Ports' tab near the top, middle of the screen to view all ports in your port group.  Right-click the port you want to disable and select 'Edit Setting'.  Under 'Miscellaneous', check the box for 'Block this port', and that will disable the specific port for you at the switch level.

Hope that helps!